# 在...之间 = between?

Tags: translation, grammar, syntax

另外还要承认人性中一些先天的不完美，就是说作为一个母亲，在自己的亲生女儿和不是亲生的灰姑娘之间，难免会更疼爱自己亲生的女儿，很难完全平等地对待她们。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 22. I would like you to confirm that a way of saying between is 在...之间:

在自己的亲生女儿和不是亲生的灰姑娘之间 = 在[自己的亲生女儿和不是亲生的灰姑娘]之间 = between [自己的亲生女儿和不是亲生的灰姑娘]。

Am I right or do I miss something?

Comment: yes, you understand it correctly

Comment: You understand it correctly, maybe memorize it as 在...和...之间 instead of  在...之间
在自己的亲生女儿和不是亲生的灰姑娘之间 = 在[自己的亲生女儿]和[不是亲生的灰姑娘]之间 = between [自己的亲生女儿] and [不是亲生的灰姑娘]

Answer (score 1):

Chinese loves to wrap things up, that's why it has:

在
自己的亲生女儿和不是亲生的灰姑娘
之间，

as a location.

But you can't translate word for word.

另外还要承认人性中一些先天的不完美，
Additionally, we must admit, human nature is imperfect,
就是说作为一个母亲，
meaning, being a mother,
在自己的亲生女儿和不是亲生的灰姑娘之间，
(if) as a mother you must choose between your biological daughter(s) and a Cinderella,
难免会更疼爱自己亲生的女儿，
it is hard to avoid loving your biological daughter more,
很难完全平等地对待她们。
and extremely difficult to afford both the same treatment.

Answer (score 0):

**在**自己的亲生女儿**和**不是亲生的灰姑娘**之间** = **between**[自己的亲生女儿] **and** [不是亲生的灰姑娘]

在 XX 和 YY 之间 = between XX and YY